# pyplot.show() not working on pycharm on ubuntu

Tags: pycharm, matplotlib

I have installed matplotlib but still when I run the program it shows:

> Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
> plt.show()

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: [How can I set the 'backend' in matplotlib in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930524/how-can-i-set-the-backend-in-matplotlib-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

The following code works in PyCharm. Pillow is packaged as `python3-pil` and matplotlib is packaged as `python3-matplotlib` in Ubuntu. The image is displayed in a new window. I copied my image, named `image.png`, into my PyCharm project's `venv` folder so that PyCharm would find it automatically.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

fname = 'image.png'
plt.imshow(Image.open(fname))
plt.show()
```

**Note:** PyCharm does not automatically find your globally installed Python packages unless the project has been configured to find them. To do this select the *Inherit global-site packages* option when you create a new project.

Select *File* → *New Project* to create a new project. Click the triangle marked by the mouse cursor in the below screenshot to show the new project's options.

[image: Create Project window]

Then check the *Inherit global-site packages* checkbox and click the  <kbd>Create</kbd>  button in the lower right corner of the *Create Project* window.

[image]